# Google Sheets: Sum matching values across list of sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to put together an investment tracking sheet.  For the overview page, I want to query and combine data from each of the account tabs but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to make that work.

Here's a link to my test sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14sZmxkM65ax9BKrkjinwOrOQPrS_xhqPPLs68Rggii4/edit

The formula I tried to use is in column J on the Overview tab.  This formula works in Excel, but not Google Sheets:

```
=IF(F2<>"",SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&Accounts&"'!"&"$N$2:$N$1000"),F2,INDIRECT("'"&Accounts&"'!"&"$O$2:$O$1000"))),"")
```

- Accounts is a named range with the 4 account tab names
- Column N on each account tab has the stock name
- Column O on each account tab has the share count
- Column F on the Overview tab has the stock names to match

If I run the same spreadsheet in Excel, the above formula works correctly and the share counts are correctly added from the 4 accounts: 120/20/50/101.

In google sheets I understand that INDIRECT doesn't support arrays, so it only shows the share counts from the first account: 100/20/0/0

So my question is if anyone can tell me how to modify the formulas from column J to work in Google Sheets?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete your whole column J and use this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(F2:F, QUERY(
 {Account1!N:O; Account2!N:O; Account3!N:O; Account4!N:O}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1"), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to replace the specific use of Account1/Account2/etc with the Accounts named range?  My goal is to not need to modify the rest of the sheet when adding/removing accounts.

Comment: @Gary no because when you create named range you cant combine multiple ranges into one named range. but, you can wrap each range into iferror like: `IFFERROR(Account1!N:O, {"",""})` - this way formula will work regardless if the sheet exists or not

Comment: Hrm, I also want the names to be customizable.  Is there any way to refer to the sheet in your formula via the names in column A?  i.e. If I rename the Account1 tab to MyAccount and change A2 to MyAccount, can your formula use A2 in some way?  i.e. instead of having to change the formula from Account1!N:O to MyAccount!N:O, it would be SOMETHING(A2)!N:O

Comment: @Gary yes, it would be: `INDIRECT(A2&"!N:O")`

Comment: Thanks, that got it working!  I hope you don't mind, but could you help me with one additional issue?  New link here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JYmQQYxRylL9xvk2CEgZECEzxhHC8VQ8D2_LaAb1EUs/
I tried extending the same formula to work for the other columns, but it claims there is a circular dependency for column N, which I don't understand since the only data being referenced is in other sheets.

Comment: Also, if you delete that formula and just fill N2,N3,N4,and N5 with 0, columns J-M will become 0/blank.  Those columns should only be accessing the account sheets, so I don't understand how that's breaking things.

Comment: @Gary formula would be: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3QKR.png